# how do I determine a cross shape with given vertices

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am having trouble forming an algorithm to determine if 12 vertices that was inputted by a user in any order, will form a cross shape in a 2D plane.
From the way I looked at it, it can be two rectangle intersecting.

Should I choose to brute force it by comparing the distances, 
I will end up having 67 distances from the 12 vertices, which to compare all of them would not be feasible.
Is there any characteristic of a cross or shape that I could use?

Comment: Define “a cross shape”.

Comment: If i had to put it, it would be a like a + sign

Comment: @eatmybananapls x too?

Comment: no angles, just a straight +.

Comment: How about a Christian cross shape with one arm longer and it’s opposite arm shorter?

Comment: Does the relative width of the arms vs. their length matter?  Should their width and length/protrusion be the same?

Comment: yes, that would be in the scope of the question, my apologies for not being more clear,  well it would be possible for one arm to be in a higher position and the opposite arm lower,  It would help if I also could get an answer or an idea to solve that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a cross shape define by two intersecting rectilinear rectangles with protrusions greater than zero on all four sides.  I believe the following algorithm will fully determine that for you.

1. Insure that none of the 12 points is identical.
2. There should only be 4 distinct X values among the 12 points.  Put them in ascending order into an array that we’ll call your X-vector.
3. Do the same with Y values creating a Y-vector with 4 distinct values.
4. Make a 4x4 array, initializing all cells to zero.
5. Go through each of the 12 values using their X and Y values along with the X-vector and Y-vector to select a cell in the 4x4 array to increment.  Thus if you had a point (12,9) and 12 was at the [0] entry of the X-vector and 9 was in the [2]entry of the Y-vector, you would increment the [0,2] cell of the 4x4 array.
6. Now your 4x4 Array should look exactly like this:

> ```
> 0, 1, 1, 0
> 1, 1, 1, 1
> 1, 1, 1, 1
> 0, 1, 1, 0
> ```

If so, then it is a cross as you have defined it.  And if not, or if it fails at any previous step, the it is not a cross.

Comment: Actually, I think that you can skip my first step.

Comment: This is amazing! thank you very much! I was under the impression that the cross should be solved via unique distance between vertices.I would have never thought of using just the unique points.

Comment: The first part is similar to my approach, but isn't the second part (with the 4x4 array) overly complicated?

Comment: @tobias_k simpler to explain and justify, I think.  And in many languages it’s a single equality comparison.

Comment: If the cross is uneven, e.g the cross body is even but the left arm vertices are higher than the right arm, for such a case, wouldn't it have more than 4 unique points? what changes can be made to solve this?

Comment: *if the cross is uneven but in context still consider a cross* I tried allowing more unique points but as it grows, sooner or later almost anything with 12 vertices would be considered a "cross"

Comment: @eatmybananapls If the left arm is higher than the right arm, then it is not the intersection of two rectilinear rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

- collect the points in a set or list
- iterate the points and find the distinct X and Y coordinates; there should be exactly four different values for X and Y, respectively; if there are more or fewer, it's not a cross-shape
- sort the distinct X and Y coordinates and call them `x1` through `x4` and `y1` through `y4`
- check whether the original list of points contains exactly the points `(x1, y2)`, `(x1, y3)`, `(x2, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, `(x2, y3)`, `(x2, y4)`, `(x3, y1)`, `(x3, y2)`, `(x3, y3)`, `(x3, y4)`, `(x4, y2)`, and `(x4, y3)`, in any order
- if there are other properties to be met, e.g. the four arms having same lengths, check those, too, using the identified distinct X and Y values